# OFFSET and LIMIT not working in laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying to use offset and limit on Laravel eloquent.

```
$start_from = 0;
$limit = 2;
$invoices = Invoice::where('calculation_complete',0)
    ->offset($start_from)
    ->limit($limit)
    ->get();
```

Instead of giving me 2 record it is giving me all the records. Where it is going wrong I am using it on other places there it is working fine.

Comment: why dont you use the [paginate()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination) method?

Comment: What is your underlying database? Also can you share what actual query is generated (using e.g. `dd(Invoice::where....->toSQL())`)

Comment: Those method work, check the rest of your code, maybe you're overwriting the variable with another call `$invoices = $user->invoices` or something like that. In all cases, not enough details to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has own function `skip` for `offset` and `take` for `limit`.

Try this:

```
$start_from = 0;
$limit = 2;

$invoices = Invoice::where('calculation_complete',0)
                ->orderBy('id','DESC')
                ->skip($start_from)
                ->take($limit)
                ->get();
```

Or, you can use `paginate`:

```
$invoices = Invoice::where('calculation_complete',0)
                ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->paginate($limit);
```

Comment: This might be the answer, but explain why you think it will help.  [From the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#limit-and-offset): *you may use the limit and offset methods. These methods are functionally equivalent to the take and skip methods,*

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5.8 following code return all rows:

```
$oldClients = OldClientModel
            ::where('offer_received', false)
            ->limit(20);
```

But when I add `->get()` after limit I've got 20 rows.